# How to make an indexedMap function for a Grid (2d List) type?

Tags: list, function, dictionary, elm

There's an `indexedMap` function for the provided `List` type: ( http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.0.0/List#indexedMap )

```
indexedMap : (Int -> a -> b) -> List a -> List b
Same as map but the function is also applied to the index of each element (starting at zero).

indexedMap (,) ["Tom","Sue","Bob"] == [ (0,"Tom"), (1,"Sue"), (2,"Bob") ]
```

I made a `Grid` type with a definition of `type alias Grid a = List (List a)`

I want to make a similar `indexedMap` function for this `Grid` type with a signature of `indexedMap : ((Int, Int) -> a -> b) -> Grid a -> Grid b`, but I'm note sure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `List.indexedMap` twice:

```
indexedMap f grid =
  List.indexedMap
    (\outer list -> List.indexedMap (\inner item -> f (outer,inner) item) list)
    grid
```

The first `List.indexedMap` handles the "outer list" and the second `List.indexedMap` the "inner lists", where `outer` and `inner` refer to the indices within those two lists, respectively.

If you prefer a more point-free style, you can also use

```
indexedMap f = 
  List.indexedMap
    (\outer -> List.indexedMap (\inner -> f (outer,inner)))
```